# OR and AND in SQL returns results which should not appear

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, conditional-statements, boolean-logic

I need to get results that would include only titles where the following combinations appear and updated within a specific date range. The problem is that the code below still returns many other titles which are not in the search condition.

The output looks like this, os it's clear that something wrong with the code. Desired output return none of this titles

[image]

```
USE My DB;--[dbo].[fn_StripCharacters]
;with cte_All as (
    SELECT
        --top 100
        ID,
        t.LastNameTx,
        t.FirstName,
        MyDB.[dbo].[fn_StripCharacters] (t.Title, '^a-z') as Stripped_Title,
        t.Title,
        t.City,
        t.State,
        t.VerificationDate,
        t.VerifiedBy,
        t.ModificationDate,
        t.ModifiedBy,
        'Higher Importance' AS Importance
    FROM
        My.dbo.MyTable t WITH (NOLOCK)
),
cte_TitleExceptions as (
    SELECT
        --top 100
        ID,
        t.LastNameTx,
        t.FirstName,
        MyDB.[dbo].[fn_StripCharacters] (t.Title, '^a-z') as Stripped_Title,
        t.Title,
        t.City,
        t.State,
        t.VerificationDate,
        t.VerifiedBy,
        t.ModificationDate,
        t.ModifiedBy,
        'Higher Importance' AS Importance
    FROM
        cte_All gc WITH (NOLOCK) -- ISCore.dbo.GovContact gc WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE
        COALESCE(CONVERT(DATE, t.VerificationDate),CONVERT(DATE, t.ModificationDate)) < DATEADD(m, -12, @DateInPast)
        AND COALESCE(CONVERT(DATE, t.VerificationDate),CONVERT(DATE, t.ModificationDate)) != CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) --@DateInPast
        AND (
            -- list of exeptions from Williamson Remot
            --     gc.Stripped_Title LIKE '%Director%'
            gc.Stripped_Title LIKE '%Human%'
            OR gc.Stripped_Title LIKE '%HR%'
            OR gc.Stripped_Title LIKE '%ITDirector%'
            OR gc.Stripped_Title LIKE '%ITOfDirector%'
            OR gc.Stripped_Title LIKE '%DirectorIT%'
            OR gc.Stripped_Title LIKE '%DirectorOfIT%'
            OR gc.Stripped_Title LIKE '%InformationTechnolog%'
            OR gc.Stripped_Title LIKE '%Finance%'
            OR gc.Stripped_Title LIKE '%CFO%'
            OR gc.Stripped_Title LIKE '%ChiefFinancialOfficer%'
            OR gc.Stripped_Title LIKE '%FinancialOffice%'
            OR gc.Stripped_Title NOT LIKE '%Engineer%'
        )
)
select
    *
from
    cte_TitleExceptions
```

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Comment: You've got a bunch of OR .. LIKE ... OR ... LIKE and then the final two lines are OR ... NOT LIKE  ... '%Engineering%' and '%Engineer%'.  That's basically going to return all of your other titles, regardless of whether they matched one of the "LIKE"s or not.  Are you sure those two are meant to be "NOT LIKE" .... or, are they meant to be outside that block, in an "AND" of their own?

Answer (score 2):

There is a flaw in your OR statements

```
...
    OR gc.Stripped_Title NOT LIKE '%Engineering%'
    OR gc.Stripped_Title NOT LIKE '%Engineer%'
...
```

you are basically saying return everything that is not like '%Engineer%' , so all the statement above this will be useless

if I understand correctly , your code should be like this :

```
...
AND (
            -- list of exeptions from Williamson Remot
            --     gc.Stripped_Title LIKE '%Director%'
            gc.Stripped_Title LIKE '%Human%'
            OR gc.Stripped_Title LIKE '%HR%'
            OR gc.Stripped_Title LIKE '%ITDirector%'
            OR gc.Stripped_Title LIKE '%ITOfDirector%'
            OR gc.Stripped_Title LIKE '%DirectorIT%'
            OR gc.Stripped_Title LIKE '%DirectorOfIT%'
            OR gc.Stripped_Title LIKE '%InformationTechnolog%'
            OR gc.Stripped_Title LIKE '%Finance%'
            OR gc.Stripped_Title LIKE '%CFO%'
            OR gc.Stripped_Title LIKE '%ChiefFinancialOfficer%'
            OR gc.Stripped_Title LIKE '%FinancialOffice%'
           
        )
AND (     
   gc.Stripped_Title NOT LIKE '%Engineer%'
 -- these two can be combined to one  
)
...
```

Comment: @eshirvana Not sure why I should say NOT LIKE I need to use LIKE to return the titles in my search sondition

Comment: @enigma6205 I'm saying nothing, you've used NOT LIKE ! , see your code.

Comment: If something has Human and need to return it this record. But if the tile is not in any other provided titles in the where clause I Do Not need it to be returned.

Comment: then its an `AND` not `OR` , see second part of my answer

Comment: @enigma6205 you are welocome, please accept as answer if it helped